# bulk mail using emacs

Tags: email

I am looking for a way to bulk generate emails in emacs.

Is there any plugin I am not aware of?
I need to read 'name', 'surname', 'email', and an additional field from a CSV and place those values in a template and send them out.

Would be very grateful for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find [gulp](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/obsolete/gulp.el) useful as a start for your own code (I wrote is 20+ years ago, I am not sure if RMS actually ever used it).